# how can i get these buttons side by side in the top right corner?

Tags: html, css

trying to get these buttons side by side (top of page http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/) but it's not working right. something with floats/text align is messed up but im not sure how to alter it.

HTML

```
<div id="icons">
        <ul>
        <li><div class="twitter">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="Seersucker_Mag">Tweet</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id))              {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script',            'twitter-wjs');</script>
        </div></li>

        <li><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com" data-type="button_count"></div>
        </li>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#icons {
    max-width: 100px;
    float: right;
    top:10px;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: none;
}

#icons ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#icons li {
display: inline-block;
}

.twitter {
    opacity:0.3;
    text-align: none;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed` and `float:right`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed` and `float:right`? Pick one or the other. If you remove `position: fixed` it works. Or if you want it fixed, use `right:0` and remove the `max-width`.

```
#icons {
    right:0;
    top:10px;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BzjHy/

Or I suppose you could float the ul right.